# Eclipse (java) is there a way to run automatically unit tests when running my app

Tags: junit

- I'm developing java under eclipse.
- I want to do some automatic playing for all the unit tests (Junit tests) before running my application.
  i.e when clicking on run as -> java application
     All the unit tests will run , and after they finish to run, the application will run.

  (I know i can run unit test and app separately, but I want to do it in one shot)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Infinitest Eclipse plugin](http://infinitest.github.io/) that runs the tests not only before you run your app, but after each change you make to your codebase. It's smart enough to detect which tests are affected by any given change so it only runs the relevant tests, it isn't a performance overhead.